# wget unable to resolve host address 'www.'

Tags: networking, wget

This is the first time i use wget so please bear with me.

I have flareget installed on my ubuntu, but i decided to try the famous wget. I have no when using flareget, but my wget is not working.

I was trying to download a movie from putlocker, it could be downloaded from flareget but not wget. This is the error on the terminal :

```
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Resolving www. (www.)... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘www.’
```

And this is the movie's url in case it has any effect :

```
http://media-b158.putlocker.com/download/15/64/42195d9d2e746f82cecd4eaebe80e0be?h=v0_gBTTgGzNSJEMi0T4y5A&e=1388834376&f=Ipman.sidofi.com.mkv.rar&domain=putlocker.com
```

I do not use the hyperlink because i think you just want to see the url, and the url seems only working on my IP.

Any help is appreciated, Thanks for your help .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are downloading the file from a file sharing site (putlocker.com), for the download to succeed just the url is not enough you need cookies too, also the urls generated are temporary and expire after some time, that is the reason you are getting 301 Moved Permanently error (url is expired).

If you want to use Wget to download from filesharing sites you need browser integration which can be provided by flashgot addon in firefox. It will transfer the fresh url as well as cookies to the wget and you won't get 301 Moved Permanently error. Since flareget has its own browser integration plugin it succeeds in downloading the file plus it has more advanced resume system wherein you can resume even after link expires by requesting a new link and updating the previous link and cookies.